# SQL Distinct cannot working if having count clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble with my sql query (Select distinct didnt work).

My sql is :

```
select distinct
count(T2.Column1)
from Table1 t2
where T2.Column1='2017-05-210'
```

The actual Column 1 data only have 3 data,
But the output is **12**

Nb :
- Column1 data is having 1 to Many situation with Column2,

Here are the actual data:

```
Column 1    Column 2
   1          A
   1          B
   1          C
   1          D
   2          A
   2          B
   2          C
   2          D
   3          A
   3          B
   3          C
   3          D
```

Can anyone help me?
Really appreciate for your attention.

Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned in our answers, your data, result and query do not match. Moreover the data you are showing is **m:n**, not 1:n (a value in column1 can be paired with many column2 values, e.g. 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D, and a value in column2 can be paired with many column1 values, e.g. 1A, 2A, 3A).

Answer (score 0):

You want to count distinct values, so do `count(distinct )`:

```
select count(distinct T2.Column1)
from Table1 t2
where T2.Column1='2017-05-210'
```

(However, your sample data and the query's data/columns do not match.)

Comment: Wow thank you very much bro jarlh,
your code was working, 
i just realize that i need "distinct" at separate parenthesis so makes that column more specificly count.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data, result and query do not match.

However, what your query does is:

1. Find all records with a `column1 = '2017-05-210'`.
2. Count all of these records where `column1` is not null (which is true for all these records, as `column1 = '2017-05-210'`).
3. This results in one number (one row, one column). But you additionally say with `DISTINCT` that you want to remove any duplicates from your result rows. With one row only there can be no duplicates, so the function is superfluous here.

So think about what you want to count really. You count distinct values (i.e. count ignoring duplicates) with `COUNT(DISTINCT column)`, but `COUNT(DISTINCT column1)` would return 1 of course, because you are only looking for *one* value which is `'2017-05-210'` (or zero in case there is no record matching this value).